# how to continue working on a git repo from my computer after system crashed

Tags: git, github

i am building a project called vue-advance-search-sort-filter and I have it on github with the URL https://github.com/emireadcode/vue-advance-search-sort-filter.

I have been committing my day-to-day work to this repo with the abovementioned URL. but my system crashed when I have not committed the latest changes to the GitHub repo.

Now, I want to pull the GitHub repo to an already existing folder in which I have to run vue commands to set the environment, which I have already done.

And I have run the following commands but my src folder is empty which means the command below is not working

```
cd vue-advance-search-sort-filter
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/emireadcode/vue-advance-search-sort-filter
git pull
```

Below is a screenshot of my console highlighting all the steps that I've run so far

[image]

Please I need help on how to get it working

Comment: try git pull origin main, it worked for me

Comment: i'd done it yet the src folder is empty and my console reads From https://github.com/emireadcode/vue-advance-search-sort-filter
 * branch            main       -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.

Comment: can you plz add a screenshot of the console with the tried steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `git init` and adding a remote: don't init anything, don't even create an empty directory, just clone the repo. For example `git clone https://github.com/emireadcode/vue-advance-search-sort-filter.git`, or the GitHub CLI equivalent.